# How can I get the list of rooms/spaces for a user (not the bot) with Google Chat API?

Tags: google-chat

Currently I can grab the list of rooms the bot is in with `chat.spaces.list()`

But is it possible to get the list of spaces for a specific user and could someone provide an example of how this could be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way for you to see the displayName on Google Chat API:

First, click on ***list*** under ***REST Resource: v1.spaces.members***
[image]

Next, under Response Body, click on ***Membership***
[image]

Next, under Resource:Membership, click on ***User***
[image]

Then lastly, under User, you can already see the ***displayName*** parameter
[image]

#### Reference link:

https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1-.spaces.members

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question.